# Can NServiceBus TimeToBeReceived be set on a per-message basis?

Tags: nservicebus

I've seen in the [documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/discard-old-messages) that `TimeToBeReceived` can be set on a message class or on the endpoint itself. I have a message class that should use `TimeToBeReceived`, but I'd like to alter the specific length of time for each individual message. Is this possible? I would have thought the option would be in the `SendOptions`, but I don't see it there.

Comment: Mostly messages of a certain type that need to be discarded need all to be discarded and not just a single one. Could you elaborate why a specific message of a certain type would require TTBR rather the contract as a whole?

Comment: They do all need to be discarded, just preferably after different lengths of time. In my system, the same message type can be configured to be sent anywhere between every minute and every 30 minutes. I'd like the TTBR to be partially calculated from that frequency.

Comment: I'm not aware of an option to dynamically set the value for TTBR. If there are not too many permutations, one option could be message type per TTBR variant. Alternatively, ask the question on the public forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was never officially answered, I suppose I'll do so myself. The answer is no, this functionality is not supported by NServiceBus.